# design pattern MVC (servlets-jsp) no output

Tags: java, jsp, oop, model-view-controller

I have a web application that asks for a name and last name in a form of HTML, then this data go to a servlet that redirects to a JSP (this JSP shows name and lastname) but when I redirect the compiler shows me the following:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I have the following files:

- index.html (is where the user write his name and lastname)
- servlet (controller,here is where the data go)
- Persona (model, is the model of the MVC)
- Resultados (its a view of a MVC that shows the data)
- Campos (other view that shows nothing)

There's a relation between index.html->servlet->resultados.jsp

Servlet:

```
String n= request.getParameter("nombre");
String last1 = request.getParameter("primerapellido");
String last2 = request.getParameter("segundoapellido");

if((n==null) || (n.equals(""))) {
   response.sendRedirect("Campos.jsp");
} else if((last1==null) || (last1.equals(""))) {
   response.sendRedirect("Campos.jsp");
} else if((last2==null) || (last2.equals(""))) {
   response.sendRedirect("Campos.jsp");
} else {
   Persona p = new Persona(n,last1,last2);
   request.getSession().setAttribute("persona1",p);              
   response.sendRedirect("Resultados.jsp");
}
```

Resultados.jsp :

```
<% Persona p = (Persona)request.getAttribute("persona1");
    String n = p.getNombre();
    String l1= p.getPrimerapellido();
    String l2=p.getSegundoapellido();

    String conca = n + l1 + l2;
 %>
```

Persona.java(model):

```
public class Persona {
private String nombre;
private String primerapellido;
private String segundoapellido;

public Persona(String nombre, String primerapellido, String segundoapellido) {
    this.nombre=nombre;
    this.primerapellido=primerapellido;
    this.segundoapellido=segundoapellido;
}

/**
 * @return the nombre
 */
public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

/**
 * @param nombre the nombre to set
 */
public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

/**
 * @return the primerapellido
 */
public String getPrimerapellido() {
    return primerapellido;
}

/**
 * @param primerapellido the primerapellido to set
 */
public void setPrimerapellido(String primerapellido) {
    this.primerapellido = primerapellido;
}

/**
 * @return the segundoapellido
 */
public String getSegundoapellido() {
    return segundoapellido;
}

/**
 * @param segundoapellido the segundoapellido to set
 */
public void setSegundoapellido(String segundoapellido) {
    this.segundoapellido = segundoapellido;
}`
```

When I send the data to Resultados.jsp the page doesn't show anything. I think the problem is between the servlet and JSP Resultados.

Comment: Please paste the error you are getting too.

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: You are going to need to provide more context. The entire exception for starters.

Comment: Improved some expressions regarding grammar and interpunction. Code formatting regarding indentation, removed unnecessary blank lines.